# TypeError: 'float' object is not callable in my python code at udacity wepsite test

Tags: python-3.x

```
sum = 0
no_list = (22,68,90,78,90,88)
for num in no_list:
    sum = sum +num
average  = sum / len(no_list)
print ("Average of no_list element is ", average )
```

Comment: Please mention what is the background actual question, what you tried and what were your expectation. You can refer stackoverflow's guide to ask good questions, as you are a newbie. Thank you.

Comment: You are required to complete the function average(x). where "x" is a list of numbers, and contains more than 3 numbers. the function is expected to return the average from that list.
Example:
input : [10,20,30,40]
output: 25
you can change the numbers in the list no_list but you are not allowed to change the variable names or edit any other code, except the function's body, doing so may jeopardize your evaluation

Comment: this is the question that is i write the code for it

Comment: when i click run he gave me that error TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

Comment: What you posted runs fine. Please post the full error so we can see where it is happening.